# How can I embed an entire GitHub Gist dynamically on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, oembed

I have some text that includes URLs to GitHub Gists. I'd like to look for those URLs and put the Gist inline in the content client-side. Some things I've tried:

#### A direct lookup to GitHub's OEmbed API.

For `https://gist.github.com/733951`, this means I do a JSON-P lookup to 
`https://github.com/api/oembed?format=json&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2F733951`,
extract the `html` property of the object, and add adding that to my page. The problem
   here is that GitHub's OEmbed API only returns the first three lines of the Gist.

#### Using the [jQuery-embedly plugin](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery).

Calling

```
jQuery('a.something').embedly({allowscripts: true})
```

works, but Embedly strips formatting from the Gist. Wrapping it in a `<pre>` tag doesn't help because there are no line-breaks.

#### Using GitHub's `.js` version of the gist.

`https://gist.github.com/733951.js` uses `document.write`, so I don't have any control over where in the page when I require it dynamically. (If I could write it into the HTML source it would show up in the right place, but this is all being done client-side.)

Answer (score 6):

I've been inspired by client side gist embedding and built a `script.js` hack library just for that (I also use it to remove the embedded link style and use my own style that fits better on my page) ...

It's more generic than just embedding gists and pasties - actually I'm using it to dynamically load some third-party widgets / google maps / twitter posts) ...

https://github.com/kares/script.js

Here's the embedding example :

https://github.com/kares/script.js/blob/master/examples/gistsAndPasties.html

**UPDATE**: gist's API since then supports *JSONP*, jQuery sample:

```
var printGist = function(gist) {
    console.log(gist.repo, ' (' + gist.description + ') :');
    console.log(gist.div);
};
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'https://gist.github.com/1641153.json', 
    dataType: 'jsonp', success: printGist 
});
```

Comment: Well, changing `document.write` will work, though that seems a bit... risky. Still, it's at least *a* solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just started a project called UrlSpoiler ([on github](https://github.com/colllin/urlspoiler)).  It will help you embed gists dynamically. It's hosted on Heroku on the free/shared platform so you can play with it, but I'd recommend copying the code you need into your own app for production use.

Comment: domain is dead, not a helpful answer

Comment: link is currently dead. @collindo

Comment: thanks @LucianNovo. Link is alive now! I changed my github username a few days ago...  sorry about that.